# Gzip uncompressed http.Response.Body

Tags: go, gzip

I am building a Go application that takes an `http.Response` object and saves it (response headers and body) to a redis hash.  When the application receives an `http.Response.Body` that is not gzipped, I want to gzip it before saving it to the cache.

My confusion stems from my inability to make clear sense of Go's `io` interfaces, and how to negotiate between `http.Response.Body`'s `io.ReadCloser` and the gzip `Writer`.  I imagine there is an elegant, streaming solution here, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*If* you've already determined the body is uncompressed, and *if* you need a `[]byte` of the compressed data (instead of for example already having an `io.Writer` you could write to, e.g. if you wanted to save the body to a file then you'd want to stream into the file not into a buffer) then something like this should work:

```
func getCompressedBody(r *http.Response) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    gz := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
    if _, err := io.Copy(gz, r.Body); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err := gz.Close()
    return buf.Bytes(), err
}
```

(this is just an example and would probably be in-line instead of as a function; if you wanted it as a fuction then it should probably take an `io.Reader` instead of an `*http.Response`).

Comment: Precisely what I needed.  Thank you!